# WTForm modelform not displaying checkbox value from db record

Tags: forms, flask, checkbox, boolean, flask-wtforms

I'm using WTForms model forms in flask and if I use it to edit an existing record all the data is submitted to the db successfully, however if you then go back to edit the record again, the checkboxes for the Boolean fields always default back to unchecked again, even though the data has been submitted correctly. However the other fields (dates, text, etc) do display the data, so the view is passing the record to form correctly. I'm  letting WTF manage the fields and input field type, so there's very little to get wrong!
None of these are foreign keys so it's a really simple setup...

Any ideas with the checkboxes/Boolean fields aren't playing ball when all the others are?
TIA

**model.py**

```
class Tests(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "tests"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    myboolean_field = Column(Boolean())
    my_date = Column(Date)
    notes = Column(String(500), nullable=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditTestForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Tests
        include_foreign_keys = True
```

**routes.py**

```
def edit_test(id):

    testdetail=Tests.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    form=EditTestForm(request.form, testdetail)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        form.populate_obj(obj=testdetail)

        db.session.commit()
        flash('Record updated!')
        return redirect(url_for('bp.rd_view_test', id=id))

    return render_template('edit_test.html', form=form, testdetail=testdetail)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, solved it I think. Posting back here in case anyone else finds the same issue:
After going round in circles for far too long, and attempting custom widgets and a whole bunch of other stuff, changing

`form=EditTestForm(request.form, testdetail)`

to

`form=EditTestForm(obj=testdetail)`

was enough to get the form to populate the boolean checkboxes correctly (?), but this then failed to save the form back to the db.

So rendering separate forms for post and get requests seems to fix it...

**routes.py**

```
def edit_test(id):

    testdetail=Tests.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=EditTestForm(request.form, obj=testdetail)
    
        if form.validate():
            form.populate_obj(testdetail)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('bp.rd_view_test', id=id))

    else:
        form=EditTestForm(obj=testdetail)
        return render_template('edit_test.html', form=form, testdetail=testdetail)
```

Feels hack-y because I haven't figured out why only the checkboxes get overridden if both request.form and the queryset are passed to the form, but it works...